# is it possible to set parameter spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size from command line in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot

I've tried to set parameter spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size from command line as a starting parameter:
`-Dspring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB`
but I'm not able to confirm it,
is it possible in such way?

Comment: what problem or doubt do you have this is correct syntax java -jar -Dspring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB application.jar

Best you to confirm this is read it in your Application.class

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

As mentioned by @Shailesh, you have to use it by that way.

Once it executes by this way, it sets the property and use it whenever required.

If you want to test it then upload the file greater than the specified limit, it should throw the error.

Comment: Therr are two aspects one if it can be done, yes it can be done the way we both explained. Another aspect is if it works, then there is only one way to find out... Test it the way @atul said